# How can I group Points to make polygon via Python

Tags: python, polygon, point, polygon-creation

I have an array of coordinates

Point= [lat,long]

ListPoint= [[38.203655,-76.113281],[38.10,-76.12],..]

I wanna make a polygon that contains all these points ? There is a project developed by [Flicker - The shape of Alpha](http://code.flickr.net/2008/10/30/the-shape-of-alpha/) but the project is not open.

Do you have any ideas how can I do that.

Comment: Are the coordinates the vertices of the polygon that you want to create or do you want to create a polygon that contains these points?

Comment: Yes, I wanna create a polygon that contains these points. Generating one.

Answer (score 6):

The following explains (1.) how to construct technically a polygon from points and (2.) different methods to construct a polygon from points.

---

**1. Tool to create a polygon from point coordinates**

I would use the [GDAL Python bindings](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Geometry-class.html#Contains) to do that.

To give you a starting point have a look at the following script:

```
from osgeo import ogr

# you have a list of points
listPoint = [[13.415449261665342, 52.502674590782519],[13.416039347648621, 52.50250152147968],[13.415787220001221, 52.501845158120446],[13.416162729263306, 52.502201097675766],[13.415406346321104, 52.502334982450677],[13.415111303329468,52.50204435400651]]
```

[image]

```
# Add the points to the ring
ring = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
for point in listPoint:
    lat = point[0]
    lon = point[1]
    print lat, lon
    ring.AddPoint(lat,lon)


# Add first point again to ring to close polygon
ring.AddPoint(listPoint[0][0], listPoint[0][3])

# Add the ring to the polygon
poly = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
poly.AddGeometry(ring)
print poly.ExportToJson()
```

[image]

---

**2. Methods to create a polygon from point coordinates**

There are two problems to think about when creating a polygon from points.

- The order of the points
- Points that might be contained by the polygon

Two methods to approach this problem:

1. [Convex Hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull): It is the smallest convex set containing all points. You can see it as a rubber band wrapped around the “outside” points.
2. [Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation): All points are connected to each other.

Comment: Should that be: ring.AddPoint(listPoint[0][0], listPoint[0][1]) ?

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing we have in Python to a standard built-in Polygon is defined in "A Python Protocol for Geospatial Data": https://gist.github.com/sgillies/2217756.

The most straightforward way to get a Python polygon is to do this:

```
# you have a list of points
listPoint = [[13.415449261665342, 52.502674590782519],[13.416039347648621, 52.50250152147968],[13.415787220001221, 52.501845158120446],[13.416162729263306, 52.502201097675766],[13.415406346321104, 52.502334982450677],[13.415111303329468,52.50204435400651]]

polygon = {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [listPoint]}
```

If you want to serialize this into GeoJSON for use with web mapping software, you'll need to reverse the order of coordinate pairs (longitude comes first in GeoJSON, KML, etc.):

```
polygon = {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[pt[::-1] for pt in listPoint]]}

import json
print json.dumps(polygon)
```

Ustroetz's example does the same thing (ExportToJson() produces the same result as json.dumps(polygon) above, but indirectly through the osgeo.gdal API.